# UIImageView inside Custom Table View Cell

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a customized table view cell which contains 3 labels and an imageView. I'm populating a table view with the table view cells. In the table view implementation, I define what I want to be shown in each table view cell. The labels work fine, but the image doesn't. I'm doing

```
[[cell subject] setText:subject];
...
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"full_path"]];
```

"subject" is a label and it works fine. But the image isn't appearing in the table view. Any ideas about what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Adriana

Problem solved: In the Table View Cell I forgot to add the referencing outlet to the image view :(

Comment: Is the image named "full_path" included in your project? Simple oversight, but it happens sometimes.

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath: code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the following:
* make sure that you init the cell values after the cell is created (viewDidLoad)
* if you are using the IB make sure that the image is connected.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `imageView` property of the UITableViewCell object points to an already defined attribute, appropriately handled by the object.
What I usually do is creating a custom cell view through Interface Builder, assign each single component that I want to be able to refer to a different tag (even this can be done in IB). Then in the code you can use this piece of code:

```
UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:yourTag];
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"full_path"];
```

This way you'll be able to use a custom number of different component, each with a different tag number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: CAUTION -- ImageView property of the UITableViewCell object is not a private attribute. [Reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You are right, I was wrong while writing the answer. What I wanted to say is that the `imageView` property already exists, and probably "overlaps" with what she wants to control.

Comment: No, the problem is the method called. I have post an answer.

Comment: I would advise against using tags to access and manage views in a custom cell.  It will work but is cumbersome and not efficient, especially if you have to access this view very much.  Its better to make a property and IBOutlet.

Comment: I created a custom cell view throw IB. I'm not using tags for the labels and everything works fine. My only problem is with the imageView...

Comment: Adriana, so you probably want to look at the answer by @TheRonin, it could be related to an error in the file path definition. If your image is in the root of the project, then you should simply use the name of the file (without path).

Answer (score 1):

When you use :

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
```

You don't need to put full path but only file name if he is in your bundle.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPict.png"];
```

If your image is not in your main bundle use (or always if you want):

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"full_path"];
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but there are a few other things to consider when choosing "imageNamed:" vs. "imageWithContentsOfFile:".  "imageNamed:" caches the image in memory for for quick access later.  If you are using the same image over and over this is the way to go.  But if it is a large image or it is not getting used repetitively you should use "imageWithContentsOfFile:" which loads from scratch every time and does not bog down memory.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, but I still don't get the image. I can get the image if I write its file name in the attributes inspector of the imageView, on the customized view cell, but I would like to do this programmatically instead from the table view class, since I don't want to show the image in every cells.

Comment: In method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you do that :`[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"full_path"]];`. This method is called when table view need a new cell, so you customize your cell in this method.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, both with the labels and the image. The labels are set properly with the text, but the image isn't.

Comment: How did you catch file path ? Like that ? `NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPict" ofType:@"png"];`

Comment: Valid the answer to close the subject !